# Multiple select, disable option

Tags: javascript, html-select

for disable option im using this:

```js
function handleSelection(source, dest) {
    
    itemRemove = dest.length - source.selectedIndex;
    for(i=dest.length-1; i>=itemRemove; i--){
        dest.options[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="s1" onchange="handleSelection(this, s2)">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id="s2" onchange="handleSelection(this, s1)">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

but this job only with 2 select. I need then this job with multiple select.
Thanks!

Comment: <select multiple .... >

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you trying to do and if you approach is good but try my code. it will work

```
function handleSelection(source, destArr) {
    for( dest in destArr){}
        itemRemove = dest.length - source.selectedIndex;
        for(i=dest.length-1; i>=itemRemove; i--){
            dest.options[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
}

<select id="s1" onchange="handleSelection(this, [s2,s3,s5])">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id="s2" onchange="handleSelection(this, [s6,s7,s8])">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my script, selecting for example 2 in the first select, in the second clear the 4 and 3, and then remains the 1 and 2. (4 - 2 = 2). It works well, but now I can do the same job with the most select